# JQuery / AJAX File Upload using FormData, file not posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This works when submitting the form directly. Perhaps I am not passing my "form" object to FormData correctly. Laravel is saying that "file" isn't being passed and when I console.log(formData), I'm seeing an object containing the proto prop but as far as I can tell none of my fields

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" action="/file">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.file-upload-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitUploadFileForm($(this)); //also tried just passing this without wrapper
});
function submitUploadFileForm(form){
    console.log(form);
    var formData = new FormData(form); //Needed for passing file
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/file',
        data: formData,
        success: function () {
            alert('done');
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
}
```

Comment: `FormData` accepts a `form` DOMElement, not a jQuery object. You need to call `submitUploadFileForm()` just passing the `this` reference to the form. You say you've already tried this, if so what was the error?

Comment: :/ maybe I rushed through testing too fast. Setting it back to just "this" worked haha thanks. If you want to throw this in as an answer I can accept it

Comment: No problem, added it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormData` accepts a `form` DOMElement, not a jQuery object. You need to call `submitUploadFileForm()` just passing the `this` reference to the `form`:

```
submitUploadFileForm(this);
```